# Most efficient way to get keys,values between two keys of an Associative array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array

```
$var = array("one"=>"one","two"=>"two","three"=>"three","four"=>"four");
```

if i passed keys  `one,three` i want to get values `one , two ,three` with keys .

now i am doing is

```
$new_array = array_diff(array_slice($var,$key1),array_slice($var,$key2));
$new_array[$key1] = $var[$key1];
$new_array[$key2] = $var[$key2];
```

is there any efficient way , please help .

Comment: what do you mean if you passed keys `0,2` you want to get `one , two ,three`? Based on what?

Comment: I don't know if i get your question right, but doesn't array_slice(array,index_begin, index_end) provide the desired behaviour?

Comment: @Adnan . Based on keys , 0 and 2 are keys

Comment: still doesn't explain why passing `0` and `2` would return `one`, `two` and `three`

Comment: @Adnan He wants to get the values where the keys are in the *range* `0 -> 2`, so `0 = one, 1 = two, 2 = three`

Comment: @DaveRandom, thank you for explaining. It was a bit counter-intuitive to me, I thought that with ranges the desired behavior would be when passing `1, 3` returns `one, two, three` that's what confused me

Comment: @user871784 , hey tha array_slice does not have 'index_end' , it has 'length' . please seee the manual . http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Answer (score 4):

You pass in a key `$from` and a key `$to`. To have something *from - to* working, you need to know the order as well. You get the order of keys with `array_keys`:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
```

Now you can locate both the offset of `$from` and `$to` keys:

```
array_slice($array, $keys[$from], $keys[$to] - $keys[$from] + 1);
```

Compile as a full example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Most efficient way to get keys,values between two keys of an Associative array
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/11358192/367456
 */

$array = array("one" => "one", "two" => "two", "three" => "three", "four" => "four");

$slice = function($from, $to) use ($array)
{
    $keys = array_flip(array_keys($array));
    if (isset($keys[$from]) and isset($keys[$to])) {
        return array_slice($array, $keys[$from], $keys[$to] - $keys[$from] + 1);
    }
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid from and/or to key.');
};

var_dump($slice('one', 'three'));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  string(3) "one"
  ["two"]=>
  string(3) "two"
  ["three"]=>
  string(5) "three"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input array has contiguous keys, why not just:

```
$newArray = array_slice($array, $key1, $key2 + 1);
```

**EDIT**

Oh wait, that will only work when `$key1 = 0`, try this instead:

```
$newArray = array_slice($array, $key1, ($key2 - $key1) + 1);
```

This still requires that `$key1 < $key2`, but from what you say I imagine it always will be.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

In order to accomplish this without looping the array (with would of course be the *easiest* way) you need to convert the string keys to numerics so they can be used with `array_slice()`. This works:

```
$var = array("one"=>"one","two"=>"two","three"=>"three","four"=>"four");
$key1 = 'one';
$key2 = 'three';

$keys = array_keys($var);
$key1index = array_search($key1, $keys);
$key2index = array_search($key2, $keys);

$newArray = array_slice($var, $key1index, ($key2index - $key1index) + 1, TRUE);

print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: hmm,  am working with an associative array . so simply can not do mathematical operations

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Well that's easily solved - just change it to `$newArray = array_slice(array_values($array), $key1, ($key2 - $key1) + 1);`

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya If you're not working with the kind of array you post in your question, how should one help you? Post the data you're working with.

Comment: when you use array_slice and work with an associative array you can set preserve_key flag true

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Do you wish to preserve the keys? Also, when working with an associative array you should work with the names of the keys and your code should be agnostic of the order the keys occur within the array. If you want to grab an arbitrary chunk of the array, it only really makes sense if the array is indexed and you are using it like a stack.

Comment: @hakre Indeed. I was just playing around with it and I came up with a similar solution, your `array_flip()` so you can reference directly by string key is definitely better.

Comment: Ah nice, preserve keys with `array_slice`. That makes it complete I'd say.